# How can you make gelatin at home?

Tags: gelatin, kosher, halal

I'm looking for something maybe from a really old recipe book, be it fish, chicken or beef. I've been searching all over and obviously most people's opinions are to buy store bought gelatin. That doesn't work for me - I want it to be kosher or halal, and I can't find that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Of course you can boil out the gelatine from bones, but purifying and dehydrating is unlikely to work in your home. It's not that there was a home recipe which nobody uses today (like e.g. with millefeuille dough), it's that people did not use gelatine for jellying anything but soup and meat pies before industrially made gelatine was available.

Comment: Well I'd like to make my own gelatin to make sweets and candies as there aren't any trustworthy kosher or halal gelatin in his country. Thought I'd give it a go.

Comment: Let's see if somebody has an idea for you, maybe the process is less complicated than I imagine. An alternative would be to use a different colloid, such as agar. But this will change the texture of the candy.

Comment: @Bash - I would recommend editing and tagging your question to reflect your need for Halal/Kosher integrity.  Otherwise the effort/reward ratio is REALLY bad for something like this.

Comment: @Bash - I don't know where you are, and it's not an answer to your question, but I had no problems finding kosher/halal gelatin on the web. Even Jell-o turns out to be kosher to my amazement! (Though not everybody seems to agree). Jell-o is halal too, provided no alcohol is used in the flavor...

Comment: You could also consider using Agar... it's plant based, so you don't need to worry about halal or kosher. http://www.joyofkosher.com/2015/12/why-everyone-is-talking-about-agar/

Comment: A simple Google search will find items that are specific to your needs that you can order online. If you can post a question here, you can find it via Google.

Comment: Typically on this site diet questions involving religion have been moved to the appropriate religions SE. You may even consider the vegan and vegetarian SE if you want advice on plant based gelatin.

Answer (score 5):

After a quick Google I found this recipe :- http://www.grassfedgirl.com/diy-make-your-own-healing-gelatin/

> **Ingredients:**
>
> 1. 3-4 lbs pastured animal bones (any kind will work, I even mix them between animals) (the more bones the more likely it will gel…fill’er
>      up! )
> 2. 4-5 quarts filtered water
> 3. 1 tbsp sea salt
>
> **Directions:**
>
> 1. Put all the ingredients in a slow cooker over night or for up to 48 hours.
> 2. Strain it off through a wire mesh strainer.
> 3. Refrigerate until firm or overnight.
> 4. Chip or scrape off any fat and save for cooking or discard.
> 5. Melt the gelatin and add fruit and sweetener to make something sweet the refrigerated again.
>
> Or use the gelatin as a base for making a soup or stew.
>
> This gelatin will keep in the fridge for a week (or a year in the
>   freezer.)

One thing to note, the recipe makes no mention of all the meaty juices which will settle to the bottom during the cooling process. So where it suggests scraping the fat off the top I would recommend flipping the big gelatin block over a slicing the bottom off also.

Also during the straining process, if you can get hold of some cheese cloth or muslin it'll help ensure there are no meat particles in there anywhere.

Comment: This is a good first shot, but it clearly doesn't produce concentrated gelatine, it produces a jelly. If the OP wanted to make e.g. gummy bears from it, he'd have to use some kind of fruit concentrate to get any kind of taste with this thing. Also, I wouldn't trust this to not taste of meat without somebody trying it and confirming that the taste is negligible.

Comment: Concentration will come by boiling the liquid down to nothing, flavour wise have you ever tasted bought gelatin? Tastes like pork fat ....

Comment: Also the same site it's from uses the recipe's produce in other fruit jelly recipes.

Comment: "boiling down to nothing" is not a good strategy with gelatine. As Wikipedia mentions, "The mechanical properties of gelatin gels are very sensitive to temperature variations, the previous thermal history of the gel, and time." It will typically not re-gel after it has been boiled too much. As for the taste, gelatin does not taste "like pork fat" to me, but even if it did, this is an acceptable taste for many desserts, I like lard pie crusts. The problem would be other, more assertive tastes being created during cooking - but again, I don't know how strong they are.

Comment: Tell you what I'll try it at work when I get a chance :-) never had an issue boiling geletin before though, for example ham hock terrine, boiling down the cooking stock to add to the meat sets it like a rock...

Comment: Might be a while with it being Christmas though...

Answer (score 3):

I just got a ton of gelatin from rendering beef suet into tallow.  And I mean gelatin, not jelly!  Unfortunately I used salt in the rendering process, so my gelatin is rather salty.  It does have a slight flavour.  The best I can explain is it tastes the way a doughnut shop smells without any of the sweetness or dessert factor.  So, maybe try this and you could have kosher fat to cook with and kosher gelatin.  I think the salt helps the rendering process, unfortunately, but I've never tried not using it.

Just a side not, I'm super weirded out by all the recipes online.  If it's a recipe to make tallow, it says to discard the gelatin.  If it's a recipe to make gelatin, it says to discard the fat. Find a way to use it all - there are hundreds of food and cosmetic uses for both.

Comment: I asked a question related to this post: [How do you get geletin from rendering beef fat?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/71683/how-do-you-get-geletin-from-rendering-beef-fat)

Comment: Suet isn't generally kosher. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelev This answer may still apply for Halal though (I can't speak to Halal rules).

Answer (score -1):

I make bone broth. I cook for up to twelve hours on my wood stove. cool take off fat. put in jars and pressure can. so it has been at quite hot temperatures. All my jars are so hard to get the broth out of the gel is so thick I have to spoon it out. So I don't thin temp will affect much. I have thought of filtering and trying in a fruit jelly perhaps a thick puree mixed through. But you wouldn't have to boil to nothing. secret is lots of knuckle bones.

Comment: The question is specifically about how to make gelatin for desserts. Presumably the author knows to boil bones. The question is how to purify it for sweet applications. This answer doesn't seem to answer the question at all.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting from [How to Make Gelatin From Animal Bones](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-to-make-gelatin-from-animal-bones/):

> Commercial gelatin is made from primarily from hides and hooves. It is refined and purified to remove any flavors

The mild taste it has gets covered up with flavoring.  This should do the trick. And amazon.com sells both halal and kosher gelatin.

Comment: I have edited your question, but now see that you are not answering the question at all. Your last sentence may be a valuable comment, but not an answer.